# Does the Silverlight player support H264/MultiView Coding (3D) Videos?

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement.js, ms-media-foundation

Given that the [Player Framework](http://playerframework.codeplex.com) allegedly supports 3D MVC encoded video via the [Media Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which MediaElement.js's Silverlight Player uses, Does the later support playing stereoscopic 3D video?

Regards,

Comment: Did that answer your question, or is there more information I can provide?

Comment: @Jeff it was of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick Answer: 'Absolutely'**

I will take a quick hack at this question, only because I use Media Foundation a great deal, and I believe your question is mostly focused on Media Foundation's support for 3D video.

I have not used Silverlight's player, nor have I utilized the **3D** video capabilities of Media Foundation, however as I am dealing with video streams in general, I constantly see API documentation which confirms the 3D support. There is much more than the links below, but should provide sufficient evidence.

A couple enums:

[MFVideo3DFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162802(v=vs.85).aspx)
   [MFVideo3DSampleFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162803(v=vs.85).aspx)

A few attributes:

[MF_ENABLE_3DVIDEO_OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162831(v=vs.85).aspx)
   [MF_MT_VIDEO_3D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162875(v=vs.85).aspx)
   [MF_MT_VIDEO_3D_FIRST_IS_LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162876(v=vs.85).aspx)
   [MF_MT_VIDEO_3D_FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162877(v=vs.85).aspx)
   [MF_MT_VIDEO_3D_LEFT_IS_BASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162878(v=vs.85).aspx)
   [MF_MT_VIDEO_3D_NUM_VIEWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162879(v=vs.85).aspx)
   [MFSampleExtension_3DVideo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162789(v=vs.85).aspx)
   [MFSampleExtension_3DVideo_SampleFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162790(v=vs.85).aspx)

A quick look at [IMFMediaEngineEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you see the a couple notable methods:

[IsStereo3D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447951(v=vs.85).aspx)
   [SetStereo3DFramePackingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447957(v=vs.85).aspx)
   [SetStereo3DRenderMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447958(v=vs.85).aspx)

When receiving samples from a source or transform, each sample has a stream id, and a media type.  You discover these upfront, so that you can efficiently handle them when processing samples (according to the stream id).  For instance closed captioning is delivered on a separate stream, in which case you can ignore them if the user does not wish to display CC. And the same is true for ancillary audio tracks (other languages, director commentary, etc).

I hope this helps.